# Two way binding with two directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My controller have a config:

```
$scope.myConfig = {
   value: 0
};
```

And template contains two directives:

```
<my-directive-one config="myConfig"></my-directive-one>
<my-directive-two config="myConfig"></my-directive-two>
```

my-directive-one:

```
<md-button ng-click="increseValue();">Increase</md-button>

function myDirectiveOne() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'directives/my-directive-one.html',
            scope: {
                myConfig: '='
            },
            link: function (scope) {

                scope.increseValue = function () {
                    scope.myConfig.value += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And when I change config inside directive one I want to get updated value in second directive that has template like:

```
<div>{{ myConfig.value }}</div>

function myDirectiveTwo() {
     return {
       templateUrl: 'directives/my-directive-two.html',
       scope: {
           myConfig: '='
       },
       link: function (scope) {
     }
   }
 }
```

Problem that in `myDirectiveTwo` value is still 0, but in controller changed fine

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: Please create a fiddle/plunker to replicate this problem.

Comment: the problem that in myDirectiveTwo value is still 0

Comment: Try using @ instead of =

Comment: @arnoldemzi when I use @ then I receive string instead of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something is wrong in the scope declaration, for both directives should be

```
scope: {
  myConfig: '=config'
}
```

and add a watcher in the second directive to be notified when the reference changes

```
//myDirectiveTwo

link: function (scope) {
  scope.$watch('myConfig', function(newVal){
     console.log('value has changed');
     //do something
  })     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize a function increaseValue but never executed it

Comment: sorry I missed template with button where increase it

Comment: Did the button works perfectly? Did it execute the function

Comment: Yes and value changed in main controller

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of `$rootscope` for your requirement.
In your directiveOne:

```
scope.increseValue = function () {
scope.myConfig.value += 1;
$rootScope.$broadcast('configChanged', val);
}
```

In your directiveTwo:

```
$rootScope.$on('configChanged', function(event, val) {
scope.myConfig = val;
});
```

you need to inject `$rootscope` to perform this by the way.